# How do I exit a wsgiserver that was started on its own thread?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, process, wsgi

I have a project that I'm working on where I hope to be able to:

- start a wsgiserver on its own thread
- do stuff (some of which involves interacting with the wsgiserver
- close the thread
- end the program

I can do the first two steps, but I'm having trouble with the last two. I've provided a simpler version of my project that exhibits the issue I have where I can do the first two steps from above, just not the last two.

A couple questions:

- How do I get the thread to stop the wsgi server?
- Do I just need to pull out the wsgiserver code and start it on its own process?

Some details of my project that may head off some questions:

- My project currently spins up other processes that are intended to talk to my wsgi server. I can spin everything up and get my processes to talk to my server, but I'm not able to get a graceful shutdown. This code sample is intended to provide a 'relatively simple' sample that can be more easily reviewed.
- there are remnants of failed attempts at solving this in the code, hopefully, they aren't too distracting.

  ```
  #Simple echo program
  #listens on port 3000 and returns anything posted by http to that port

  #installing required libraries
  #download/install Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 for Python
  #https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266
  #pip install greenlet
  #pip install gevent

  import sys
  import threading
  import urllib
  import urllib2
  import time
  import traceback
  from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer, WSGIHandler
  from gevent import socket

  server = ""

  def request_error(start_response):
      global server
      # Send error to atm - must provide start_response
      start_response('500', [])
      #server.stop()
      return ['']

  def handle_transaction(env, start_response):
      global server
      try:
          result = env['wsgi.input'].read()
          print("Received: " + result)
          sys.stdout.flush()
          start_response('200 OK', [])
          if (result.lower()=="exit"):
              #server.stop()
              return result
          else:
              return result
      except:
          return request_error(start_response)

  class ErrorCapturingWSGIHandler(WSGIHandler):
      def read_requestline(self):
          result = None
          try:
              result = WSGIHandler.read_requestline(self)
          except:
              protocol_error()
              raise # re-raise error, to not change WSGIHandler functionality
          return result

  class ErrorCapturingWSGIServer(WSGIServer):
      handler_class = ErrorCapturingWSGIHandler

  def start_server():
      global server
      server = ErrorCapturingWSGIServer(
      ('', 3000), handle_transaction, log=None)

      server.serve_forever()

  def main():
      global server

      #start server on it's own thread
      print("Echoing...")
      commandServerThread = threading.Thread(target=start_server)
      commandServerThread.start()

      #now that the server is started, send data
      req = urllib2.Request("http://127.0.0.1:3000", data='ping')
      response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
      reply = response.read()
      print(reply)

      #take a look at the threading info
      print(threading.active_count())

      #try to exit
      req = urllib2.Request("http://127.0.0.1:3000", data='exit')
      response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
      reply = response.read()
      print(reply)

      #Now that I'm done, exit
      #sys.exit(0)
      return    

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  ```